# Having an error in DataBinding in kotlin app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to bind data in my kotlin android app, I was following this tutorial on codelab [Link to Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-data-binding-basics/#2) I did everything same.

But while importing `ActivityMainBinding` in `MainActitvity.kt` file ide keeps on showing me error in red text.

I did enabled dataBinding in app level gradle file Here

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

> Here I have imported and initialized dataBinding

```
import android.content.Context
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import android.hardware.input.InputManager
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
//import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import com.example.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        binding.done_button.setOnClickListener{
            addNickname(it)
        }
    }

    private fun addNickname(view: View) {


        binding.apply{
            nickname_text.text = binding.nickname_edit.text
            invalidateAll()
            nickname_edit.visibility = View.GONE
            done_button.visibility = View.GONE
            nickname_text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }



        //Hide the Keyboard

        val inn = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inn.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)

    }
}
```

Error i get while trying to build gradle anyway. I thought to give it a try.

```
Compilation Error
```

I am new To Android.

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

tools:context=".MainActivity">

```
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >


    <TextView
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            style="@style/name_style"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nickname_edit" style="@style/name_style" android:hint="what is your nickname"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Done"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/done_button"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nickname_text" style="@style/name_style"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                style="@style/name_style"
                android:text="@string/bio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bio_text"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

> error in log

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public val Activity.done_button: Button! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
public val Dialog.done_button: Button! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
public val android.app.Fragment.done_button: Button! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
public val android.support.v4.app.Fragment.done_button: Button! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main 
Unresolved reference: it    
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public val Activity.nickname_edit: EditText! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
public val Dialog.nickname_edit: EditText! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
public val android.app.Fragment.nickname_edit: EditText! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
public val android.support.v4.app.Fragment.nickname_edit: EditText! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main

> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
```

Comment: Please share your MainActivity xml file

Comment: first of all xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" this lines are multiple times. remove from layout tag. Also your error itself says error: duplicate attribute

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan i changed that duplicate attribute error has been removed but there is still compilation error and ide still shoes me the same error in `MainActivity.kt` while initializing `dataBinding`

Comment: Also add "kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1" this line in build.gradle

Comment: You can ignore the error within `MainActivity`. That's just an issue with the analysis.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan  This is not syncing. I am getting error something like this `Gradle DSL method not found: 'kapt()'
Possible causes:
The project 'AboutMe' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.1 and sync project

The project 'AboutMe' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin`

Comment: got it wait adding my answer

Comment: kapt plugin added?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan yes i did add the kapt plugin in app level gradle file

Comment: `dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0'
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the namespace declarations to your layout tag, and remove the duplicates. It should look like this after the changes have been made:

```
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
```

After that, make sure to **clean and rebuild your project**.

Comment: I changed that but still i am getting error while adding data binding .

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt your project? I see that you've edited your question. There seems to be a formatting error with it. What is the error that you're getting now?

Comment: I was getting help from previous answer posted on my question have a look there, afeter adding all this i am getting error while syncing  this is the error i get while syncing `Gradle DSL method not found: 'kapt()'
Possible causes:
The project 'AboutMe' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.1 and sync project
The project 'AboutMe' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
`

Comment: Undo all the changes you made that was suggested by that answer. It was the "kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0'" that produces your new error.

Comment: I removed `kapt` this is the error while i am trying to compile `Compilation error. See log for more details`

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: See my MainActivity.kt   file ide shows error while i am trying to initialize DataBinding.

Comment: `.setOnclickListener`, it should be `.setOnClickListener` with a capital C

Comment: Remove the import statement `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`

Comment: After doing this i got more error then before something related to references.

Comment: Can you update your question with the entire contents of your files?

Comment: I think i have already added everything, I have added `MainActivity.kt` and `Activity_main.xml` i have added entire code of these files what else do you want me to add.

Comment: From your import statements down to the very last line. I think you've missed something you can't point out. I was just trying to help. I haven't had this ton of errors while implementing data binding on my app.

Comment: I did add my all the code from `MainActivity.kt` have a look to my question.

Comment: Change `binding.done_button.setOnClickListener{` to `binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener{`

Comment: As well as `nickname_text.text = binding.nickname_edit.text` to `nickname_text.text = binding.nicknameEdit.text`

Comment: This is working now, But how I mean don't they refer to id ? Anyway thank you

Comment: Data Binding parses the id's you've added in the layout files, but with the java variable conventions, they are parse without the underscores and converted into camel case. If I had answered your question, please mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 1) You need to add distributionUrl in gradle.wrapper-properties for latest android studio version. Your URL must be

`distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`

2) data binding dependancy in-app level Gradle file

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0'
```

and also add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

3) Add kotlin Gradle plugin project level Gradle dependency.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

After completing above all just clean, build and rebuild project.

Comment: everything is already added the same as you suggested in your answer still, I am getting the same error